# Stuck with double integral $\iint xe^{y^2} \,dy \,dx$

Tags: calculus

I can't get the first integral, so this really isn't a double, since I'm stuck on the first one.

$$\int_{-2}^0 \int_{x^2}^4 xe^{y^2} \,dy\, dx$$

Here are my steps:

1. Since I'm integrating on with respect to $y$ first, I move the $x$ outside the integral and simply integrate $e^{y^2} \, dy$ .

I get $x(e^{y^2})/(2y)$ evaluated from $y= x^2$ to $4$.

When I plug in the evaluations, I get:
$xe^{16} / (8) - e^{x^4}/(2x)$

I break this in to two integrals.

I don't know how to integrate that 2nd piece  $-e^{x^4}/(2x)$.
Doesn't seem to integrate via substitution nor partial fractions.  I can't get integration by parts to work either.  Stuck even before I get to the second integral!  What am I not seeing?

Thanks.

Comment: Tip: put mathematical symbols between $ signs to make them render correctly.

Comment: The integral of $e^{y^2}$ is actually not an elementary function, so instead you should interchange the order of integration.

Comment: You can't integrate $\int e^{y^2} dy$ into elementary functions.  Flip the order of integration, integrate with respect to $x.$  And, if you are lucky, you will get a result that will allow you to make the substitution $u=y^2.$

Comment: @Sloan The double integral you edited is wrong, and I think you shouldn't have deleted *writing instructions* by the OP: it is $\;y\;$ which is between $\;x^2\;$ and $\;4\;$ , and in your integral these look like the limits for $\;x\;$ ...

Comment: All the editors have edited or miscopied the double integral. This is one reason more why **nobody should delete words the OP wrote** !

Comment: @DonAntonio You are correct, apologies, original wording will get added back in.

Comment: For the future generations (??): The integral the OP means by his words is $$\int_{-2}^0\int_{x^2}^4 xe^{y^2}dydx$$

Comment: The antiderivative of $e^{y^2}\,dy$ is NOT $e^{y^2}/(2y)$.  You can check that by differentiating via the quotient rule. $\qquad$

Comment: My question here will expose a hole in my integration knowledge, how do I know when to use one order of integration vs the other?  Doesn't the integral e^(y^2) integrate as I showed in my step 2?

Comment: OHHHHH!  I see now that I have the wrong antiderivative!!!!  I don't think I'm ready for this test on Friday!!!  Back into the books.  Thank you.

Comment: I need to learn how to post here appropriately so that I'm not using awkward wording, but using mathematical expressions.  I'll review the help page to ensure in the future I input my questions so people who are spending their time to help are not trying to figure out what was meant.  This is totally my fault and I'll figure how how to type here correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Change the order of integration, and get:

$$\int_0^4\int_{-\sqrt y}^0xe^{y^2}\,dx\,dy=-\frac12\int_0^4 ye^{y^2} \, dy = -\left. \frac14 e^{y^2}\right|_0^4=-\frac14\left(e^{16}-1\right)$$

Comment: After studying this, I think the 2 questions I have are:

Comment: (a) How do I know to flip the order of integration? and (b) why use -sqrt(y) instead of +sqrt (y)? {although I can see it doesn't matter in the outcome whether I use the positive or negative square root}

Comment: @user163862 (a) You don't. Sometimes you try when the integral presented to you sucks, and sometimes that helps, sometimes it doesn't. (b) If you "turn over" a drawing of the original integration area, you can see that $\;y\;$ travels between zero (from below) and four (above), while $\;x\;$ does the same between $\;-\sqrt y\;$ (below) and zero (above). If you get confused and think it is $\;x\;$ between $\;0\;$ and $\;\sqrt y\;$ , observe that in the original expression the function is **negative** as $\;-2\le x\le 0\;$ and  the exponential is always positive...

Comment: I now understand about swapping the order of integration.  I don't understand how to get these new limits on the integrals. Can you step me thru that?

Comment: Specifically, what happens to the original limit of integration of x=-2?